# What is the best way to store an XML file in a database using sqlalchemy-flask?

Tags: python, xml, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a Flask app that I'd like to have store xml files in a database. I'd like to use `flask-sqlalchemy`. I've seen that in regular old `sqlalchemy` it is possible to use the `LONGTEXT` type. I believe this would work for my use case.

I would like to know (1) if `LONGTEXT` would be the best way store xml files and, if so, (2) how to use `LONGTEXT` within the `flask-sqlalchemy` syntax.

What should {insert-name-here} be in the code below? Will I need to install additional dependencies to use whatever is suggested?

```
xml_column = db.Column(db.{insert-name-here})
```

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html try TEXT or STRING, the docs description seems to suit your purpose

Comment: Flask-SQLAlchemy *is* SQLAlchemy, with Flask specific addons that make the integration smoother. What applies to one applies to the other. `db` exposes almost everything from `sqlalchemy` and `sqlalchemy.orm` namespaces, so `db.LONGTEXT` is an option.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks! That'd be awesome if it's that simple. But, I didn't see LONTEXT is standard slqalchemy either. I am likely not going to be able to test your suggestion for a few days here. But, if it does work, would you mind making it an answer?

Comment: @Attack68 Thanks for your response! String's too short for me. And, I'm just a bit worried that text is only an interface for the SQL type TEXT and not MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT as well. I don't see how sqlalchemy would be able to provide one interface for all three of those.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I ended up finding some time. LONGTEXT is not a supported type. I have seen that there is an added library that can be installed to use LONTEXT with sqlalchemy, but I'm not sure how this works with flask-sqlalchemy.

Comment: Are you using MySQL? If so, and you wish to use `LONGTEXT`, just use [sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.LONGTEXT](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.LONGTEXT).

Comment: @IljaEverilä  Yes, I'm using MySQL. Are you saying that if I `from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import LONGTEXT` I should be able to build out my column model with `db.Column(LONGTEXT)`? Flask-sqlalchemy will not have problems handling that?

Comment: No problems, because Flask-SQLAlchemy **is** SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score -2):

I use python some time.
I use [xml.etree.ElementTree] package to read or write xml data in python.

I use it like:
'''
    #import
    Import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

```
#xml file
_xml = 'c:/.../test.xml'

#read
tree = ET.parse(_xml)
root = tree.getroot()
h_data = root.findall('h')

#write
root = ET.Element('test')
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write(_xml), encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=1)
```

'''

More you can see documents.

Xml file can save as a txt, but best the encoding is utf8.
I think xml data is not best for python.

The best is json data.
Hope I can help you.

Comment: OP was asking about storing XML files in a database using Flask-SQLAlchemy.